# JFrame adding 22 pixel offset (java.awt.Insets) to top of the Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I'm creating a simple Break Out style game. The main game extends JFrame and I'm adding a JPanel to the frame.

When I was using paint() to draw the game graphics the items sat within the window as expected (i.e by their x, y coordinates).

I've updated the code to use BufferStrategy as I was getting flickering. Since the, the graphics that are rendered are offset by 22px.

This means the Bricks are off the top of the screen!

The code is as follows:

```
package BreakOut;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;


public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

GameStateManager gsm = new GameStateManager();
BufferStrategy strategy;

public Game() {

    //add menu state to GameStateManager
    gsm.add(new MenuState(gsm));
    createFrame();


    while(true)
    {
        gsm.update();
        //repaint();
        render();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }
}


public void createFrame()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    frame.add(this);        
    frame.pack();       
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = frame.getBufferStrategy();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println(frame.getInsets());
}


public void render()
{
    Graphics g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
    super.paint(g);
    gsm.render(g);
    g.dispose();
    strategy.show();
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    switch(gsm.getState())
    {
        case MAIN_MENU:
        if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            //add the PlayState to the Stack and update enum value
            gsm.add(new PlayState(gsm, this));
        }
        break;
        case PLAYING:
            if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                //add the PlayState to the Stack and update enum value
                gsm.add(new PauseState(gsm));
            }
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {                   
                gsm.pop();
            }
            break;
        case GAME_OVER:
            if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {                   
                gsm.pop();
            }
            break;
    }
    //send input to GameStateManager
    gsm.keyPressed(k.getKeyCode()); 
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
    gsm.keyReleased(k.getKeyCode());        
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
    gsm.keyTyped(k.getKeyCode());   
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game();

}
```

}

When I output System.out.println(frame.getInsets()); I get

```
java.awt.Insets[top=22,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but can't figure out why adding BufferStrategy would create the JPanel to be offset by 22px

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Frames have borders and decorations, which is included within the bounds of the frame (they don't get added to the outside), from the looks of things you're using MacOS and the 22pixels to the top is the window title.

Best solution is, don't use the frame as the render surface, instead, use the `Game` class.  This will mean it will need to extend from `java.awt.Canvas` instead of `javax.swing.JPanel` and you will need to create the `BufferStrategy` from it

If you override the `Canvas`'s `getPreferredSize` method, you can use `pack` on the frame it will pack the window around this, so the physical frame will be larger then the content, but the content will be the size you would prefer

You will also want to move you main/game loop to separate thread, as this is current in the risk of blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which could cause you no end of issues (like never getting a key event)

Comment: That's great, thanks :) Threads are the next thing on my list. What's the best method using threads for the game loop? Would I implement Runnable??

Comment: Generally, yes, it's generally recommended to use a `Runnable` and pass it to an instance of `Thread` (via the it's constructor).  Remember, Swing is not thread safe, but since your using a `BufferStrategy`, that shouldn't be an issue as `BufferStrategy` and Swing components don't play well together

Comment: Thanks once again :) So, for a game, would you generally use Canvas to render the game graphics? Would a game library such as libgdx have it's own methods of creating the window and drawing to the screen or would it use Swing and AWT??

Comment: Game kits would probably rely either on a `Canvas` and a `BufferStrategy` or provide there own native peer which would be attached to the `Canvas` depending on there implementations