# Why do the pixels appear to be offset in my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm relatively new to programming, starting off with Java and am beginning to learn the basics of Swing. Unfortunately, while creating my first JFrame, I noticed that the pixels seem to always be offset by 20-30px on most sides.

Specifically, I created a simple for loop to draw grid lines with Graphics2D. As seen below, the gridlines obviously do not align with the edge of the frame like I would expect them to.

[Here's the window when I hit run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNjco.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    MyFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Graphics Test");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            g2D.drawLine(i*50, 0, i*50, 600);
            g2D.drawLine(0, i*50, 600, i*50);
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Someone else asked a question like this and this was the suggested fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/28125531/15310387.

Comment: Typically you would do drawing like this in a panel, not directly in a frame. You may get results closer to your expectations.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, I believe this was the problem.

Comment: also typically you would not override `paint`, but `paintComponent`

Comment: Answer to the question "Why" - because the frame also has a title bar (`setUndecorated(true)` to see it without that... but be warned, there will be no button to close it)

Comment: Oracle has a radical tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that goes through the basics of creating an effective Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.